# Server cascading failure

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat, server

this might be a totally noob question.
 We just migrated to AWS a week back. We have two separate apps , call them App1 and App2. For every request that App1 receives , it makes a web service call to App2 with a read timeout of 2 sec.So ,if the response isn't delivered within 2 sec,it is aborted.However, App2 server is facing some problems due to which sometimes App2 server goes down. But the problem is that whenever App2 server goes down,App1 server goes down with it. And when it comes back up ,the App1 server immediately comes back up as well.
This is weird problem.What do you guys think is happening ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that requests are piling up on app 1 (due to increased latency) as app 2 goes down, which eventually causes app 1 to become unresponsive as well. I would also look into what actually happens when you abort your request after the two second timeout. Are you actually making sure the connection is aborted? If not, you may be using up system resources for dead connections.

But the above is just guessing in the dark; I think we need more information to make more educated guesses :).

Comment: I should also add that there is hardly any tracking.We usually get 1 or 2 GET requests a second. Also,this problem only happened since we've moved to AWS. Whenever App2 server used to go down on Digital Ocean , App1 used to work like it normally would.